# Calculate the total scrollTop and scrollLeft of an element

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip, scrolltop

I want to display a tooltip when hovering over an element. The tooltip **has** to be *position: fixed; z: index: 1* or it will not appear above the other panels in the piece of software that I am using. The problem is that with position: fixed, if there are any scrolls active on the page then the tooltip doesn't appear in the correct place relative to my original element.

I've tried to calculate the amount of scroll on one of my element's parents and to counter that in the positioning of my element using JQuery:

```js
$( '.tooltipContainer' ).mouseenter( function(){
 var scrollX = $('.elementWithScrollBar').scrollLeft();
 var scrollY = $('.elementWithScrollBar').scrollTop();
 $( '.tooltip' ).css({
    'margin-left':'-=' + scrollX,
    'margin-top':'-=' + scrollY
  });
});
$( '.tooltipContainer' ).mouseleave( function(){
 var scrollX = $('.elementWithScrollBar').scrollLeft();
 var scrollY = $('.elementWithScrollBar').scrollTop();
 $( '.tooltip' ).removeAttr('style');
});
```

```css
.elementWithScrollBar {
  background-color: gray;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 30px;
 overflow: scroll;
 width: 400px;
}
.tooltipContainer {
 display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 500px;
}
.tooltip {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 color: #000000;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #CC0000;
 display: none;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 position: fixed;
 text-align: center;
 width: 300px;
 z-index: 1;
}
.tooltipContainer:hover .tooltip {
 display: block;
}
.box {
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV class="elementWithScrollBar">
  <DIV class="tooltipContainer">
    Hover over me
    <SPAN class="tooltip">
      The tooltip should follow the text
    </SPAN>
  </DIV>
  <DIV class="box">
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

I'm not sure that defining scrollLeft and scrollTop and adding or subtracting them on mouseenter and mouseleave is the best solution to my problem but it works in simple situations (any advice welcome though).

My problem is that my element has lots of parents and all of them could feasibly have a scroll component. Is there a way to sum all of the scrollTop and scrollLeft values for all of the parents of an element so that I can work out exactly where to place my tooltip?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the wanted behaviour is.In the snippet your Tooltip stays fixed to the Texts left edge, on JSFiddle its always at the same position no matter where you scroll. https://jsfiddle.net/h5ptkz0g/

Comment: I intend the tooltip to stay in the same place relative to the text irrespective of scrolling so what I attempted obviously wasn't working as well as I'd like.
I've now managed to sum the scrollLefts and scrollTops of all parents thus:

`var scrollX = 0
var scrollY = 0
$(this).parents().each(function(){
 scrollX += $(this).parents().scrollLeft();
 scrollY += $(this).parents().scrollTop();
});`

but I'm still not sure that the way I have actually used the variables (scrollX and scrollY) to position the tooltip is optimal.

Comment: Did you test the jQuery UI or Bootstrap tooltips? You can specifiy in which container the tooltip will be appended, allowing you  to position your tooltip relative to your <body>. And you won't have to clutter your HTML structure that much cause the tooltips will be generated on the fly.

Comment: No, I've only used pure CSS but, like I said, the need to put _position: fixed_ is meaning that I am getting into trouble with scrolls. I'll check out the other tooltips, thanks a lot for the help.